# 2 different DBMS in 1 node instance

Tags: mysql, node.js, database, mongodb

I have an existing project that needs to be connected to another existing project.

1 project (Ecommerce) uses MongoDB with Mongoose as the other 1 (a turnstile system) uses mySQL.

Now what I want to do is every time a user buys a ticket in my ecommerce project is that it inserts data in both databases.

Is it possible to connect to both databases in 1 project (API of the ecommerce one).

Comment: Absolutely.  Your custom nodeJS code could certainly create two connections and respond to a single web request by inserting into both MySQL and MongoDB.  Keep in mind, there is no ACID transactions between the two.  If the MySQL accepts the insert, but MongoDB rejects it you could have an out of balanced situation.

Comment: I would generate a **single** event to create the ticket in one of them. That service will store and process the ticket, and will produce a second event that will create the ticket in the second service. Otherwise, you risk permanent data inconsistencty.